# Implementing service queryables: IQueryable to IEnumerable and back

Tags: linq, wcf, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

In RIA Services (and probably other frameworks such as WCF Data Services) one can implement data services methods by supplying methods returning an IQuerably. For example:

```
IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    return this.DbContext.Customers.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted);
}
```

A query from the client can then supply an additional filter (among other things). Both the client-provided filter and the filter for returning only undeleted customers will be combined an sent to the database in SQL by entity framework (or whatever ORM is used).

Often entity framework isn't powerful enough to express the query one wants to write, in which case we have to go to linq to objects:

```
IQueryable<CustomerWithFluff> GetCustomers()
{
    var customers =
        this.DbContext.Customers
        .Include("FluffBits")
        .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
        .ToList();

    return
        from c in customers
        select new CustomerWithFluff()
        {
            CustomerName = c.Name,
            ComplexFluff = String.Join(", ", from b in c.FluffBits select b.FluffText)
        };
}
```

The sql to the database will now still contain the restriction on "IsDeleted", but not any further filter provided by a client: Those will be applied on the linq to objects level after all the data has already been fetched.

If I don't care to let the client filter on any of the data that I need to compose with linq-to-objects (only "ComplexFluff" in this example), is there a way to still allow filtering on the properties that are simply projected (only "CustomerName" in this example)?

Comment: Your last paragraph, containing the actual question, is not clear. I would suggest to rephrase it or give an example of what you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, however is not as simple as one can expect. You have to override the

```
public override IEnumerable Query(QueryDescription queryDescription, out IEnumerable<ValidationResult> validationErrors, out int totalCount)
```

method, where you can get, in queryDescription.Query the actual query and Expression that is going to be executed against your Queryable (that is, what is being returned by queryDescription.Method.Invoke(this, queryDescription.ParamterValues)).

You can then get the expression sent by the client and pass it to your method (maybe as a reference to some sort of field in you domainService, don't forget that WCF Ria Services are instantianted at each call, i.e. like a regular wcf perCall instancing model) where you'll have to combine

```
var customers =
        this.DbContext.Customers
        .Include("FluffBits")
        .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
```

prior to the "ToList()" method call.

Not easy, but quite possible

Comment: Ok, that got me a good deal further. What I still don't know is how to combine the two queries. I have the one from the queryDescription stored as a member in the service class (I suppose that one has a rather useless IQueryProvider) and the IQueryable with the entity framework query provider that is my query. I would now want to put all the filters and sort orders of the former into the latter - but how do I do that?

Comment: Exactly. In order to do that you need an Expression Visitor. Some years ago I wrote a small post that demonstrate more or less that, you can still found it [here](http://mcasamento.blogspot.it/2010/10/combinare-due-query-linq.html) though it's in Italian it should be easy to translate. If you use linqpad I've also just made a script out of it that you can download [here](http://share.linqpad.net/aai66n.linq).
Also, take in mind that you need a rather complex rewriter since you're going to apply an expression from an entityType (CustomerWithFluff) to another (Customer)

Comment: I filed a new question for this specific problem of combining the queries at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207094/how-to-apply-domainservice-query-to-an-iquerable. I would think that whatever I have to do, it's probably already implemented in the RIA Services libraries - after all, if it weren't, why would they represent the client-side query as an `IQueryable` in `DomainService.Query` at all? And thank you for the additional pointers, I will research them.